# class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [LClass;

Tags: java, txt

¡Buenas!

Esta práctica lo he realizado de otra forma. Pero estoy intentandolo como lo tenia pensado en un principio pero me da fallo en una linea y aún buscando información no comprendo del todo el porqué de dicho fallo.

En esta práctica consiste en un menu (que lo hice con do-while), con 6 opciones. Vamos a enfocarnos en las dos primeras opciones.

La primera es crear un fichero directamente de otro. Las lineas que contiene dicho fichero seria algo como:

**|145|780|366|1999-12-12|2022-12-12|1200.00|0.0|3|Perez, Luis**

---

Bueno, como vereis en el codigo de esta primera opcion , leo el fichero, y con el split(), separo la linea en partes, cada parte la convierto a un tipo de dato concreto.

Posteriormente , cada vez que recorre el fichero, creo un empleado con dichas partes asignadas.

```
 case 1: //Crear el fichero a partir del fichero de seguridad
                     
                     
                     
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero));

                    escribiendo_fichero = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichero_s));
                    
                     try {
                         
                         
                        int cont = 0; /*Este contador nos servira para saber a partir de que linea a la hora de recorrer el fichero
                                        escribimos dichas lineas*/
                        
                        int contEmpleado = 0;

                        while((linea=reader.readLine())!=null) { /*Establecemos la variable (linea) a la lectura de cada linea
                                                                 del fichero. Mientras que no llegue al final del fichero.*/
                             
                             cont++;
                             contEmpleado++;

                                if (cont>18) { /*A partir de la 18, pues simplemente fui al documento original y vi en que linea empezaba los registros que
                                                que nos interesan */
                                    
                                    
                                    parts = linea.split("\\|");
                                    
                                    campo1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                                    campo2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                                    campo3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
                                    
                                    
                                    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


                                    campo4 = parser.parse(parts[4]);
                                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                    String formattedDate = formatter.format(campo4);

                                    campo4 = parser.parse(parts[4]);
                                    campo5 = parser.parse(parts[5]);

                                    
                                    campo6 = Double.parseDouble(parts[6]);
                                    
                                    if(parts[7] == "NULL") {
                                        
                                        campo7 = Double.parseDouble(parts[7]);
                                        
                                    } else{
                                        
                                        campo7 = 0.0;
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                    campo8 = Integer.parseInt(parts[8]);
                                    campo9 = String.valueOf(parts[9]);//Parts[9] corresponde a un String. No hace falta.
                                    
                                    empleado[contEmpleado] = new Empleado(campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6, campo7, campo8, campo9);
                                    

                                    escribiendo_fichero.writeObject(empleado[contEmpleado] + "\n"); 
                                    
                                    

                                }
                         }
                        System.out.println(((Object)empleado).getClass().getName());
                        
                        escribiendo_fichero.flush(); //Vaciamos el escritor | Empujara cualquier cosa que pueda haber quedado ahi temporalmente para asegurarse de que esté enviada al buffer de forma definitiva
                        //Cerramos ambos ficheros.
                        escribiendo_fichero.close();
                        reader.close();  
                         
                        System.out.println("\n Escribiste el fichero");

                           
                      }  catch(Exception e){
                         e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                     
                     

                     
                 break;
```

En el siguiente caso, intento leer el objeto creado en el fichero:

```
                 case 2: // Mostrar ordenados todos los registros
                     

                    
                    ObjectInputStream leer_directo = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream (fichero_s));
                    
                    Empleado[] personal_recuperado = (Empleado[]) leer_directo.readObject();
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    for (Empleado e : personal_recuperado) {
                        
                        System.out.println(e);

                    }

                    
                    break;
```

El error me dice que se encuentra en la linea de :

```
Empleado[] personal_recuperado = (Empleado[]) leer_directo.readObject();
```

Y el error se describe asi:

**class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [Lpruebaexamen.Empleado; (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [Lpruebaexamen.Empleado; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')**

---

Un saludo y ¡Gracias!

Comment: ObjectInputStream sirve para leer objetos, es decir, bytecode de objetos guarado obviamente en formato binario

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente ya tienes este error solucionado, pero estaba teniendo el mismo error en otras clases de mis ejercicios, y quizás ayude la "solución" a la que he llegado, no por ser correcta en sí sino porque al ser muy mejorable es altamente probable que alguien pueda mejorarla a partir de lo que he llegado. Cabe recalcar que aún estoy aprendiendo y que realmente no entiendo el por qué de ese error.

Al preguntárselo a ChatGPT, obtengo esta respuesta:
[image: Respuesta de ChatGPT error casting String a objeto]

El ejercicio radica principalmente en un problema de composición, donde la clase **Cartas** hace referencia a una carta de la baraja española, cuyos atributos son el palo (Si es oros, bastos, espadas o copas), su número y por ende su valor. La clase **Baraja**, que es realmente en la que se basan los test Junit 5, es una clase que tiene como atributos un array de **Cartas**. Su valor es como sigue el siguiente diagrama:

[image: Diagrama de valor de los objetos Carta]

Este error era un output del Debugger de Eclipse al estar depurando las clases de prueba con Junit 5. Aún así el Test del que hablo de donde obtengo este error se basa en métodos únicamente de **Carta**, ya que los Test de **Baraja** se basan en verificar la ordenación por insercción en el array. El método es, especificamente:

```
    @Test
public void testEqualsCarta() {

    Carta carta1 = new Carta("O", 5);
    Carta carta2 = new Carta("O", 2);
    Carta carta3 = new Carta("E", 2);
    Carta carta4 = new Carta("O", 2);

    assertEquals(true, carta1.equals(carta1));
    assertEquals(true, carta2.equals(carta2));
    assertEquals(true, carta3.equals(carta3));
    assertEquals(true, carta2.equals(carta4));

    assertEquals(false, carta3.equals(carta1));
    assertEquals(false, carta3.equals("MiCarta"));
    assertEquals(false, carta3.equals(new Integer(8)));

}
```

Los dos últimos *assertEquals* pasan por parámetro dos instancias, el penúltimo una instancia explícita de ***String*** y el último es una instancia del Wrapper ***Integer***

Al intentar utilizar el Step Into en la tercera línea del siguiente método **equals**, Eclipse me lleva directamente a las librerías de Java encargadas de lanzar las excepciones, donde el **obj** pasa a ser una excepción, por lo que no puedo entender, interpretando el Debugger exactamente la razón por la que no es posible hacer un casting de **String** a mi clase **Carta**.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
Carta otraCarta = (Carta) obj;
    if(this.palo.equals(otraCarta.palo) && this.numero==otraCarta.numero && this.valor==otraCarta.valor) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Al no ser este un proyecto de programación real, sino sencillamente un ejercicio de una de mis asignaturas, solo me ha interesado lograr que los Test Junit den verde. La solución a la que he llegado, ha sido la siguiente:

```
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this.getClass()!=obj.getClass() && obj.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
        String objString = (String) obj;
        Carta otraCarta=new Carta(objString);
        if(this.palo.equals(otraCarta.palo) && this.numero==otraCarta.numero && this.valor==otraCarta.valor) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else if(this.getClass()!=obj.getClass() && obj.getClass().equals(Integer.class)) {
        Integer objInteger = (Integer) obj;
        Carta otraCarta=new Carta((int) obj);
        if(this.palo.equals(otraCarta.palo) && this.numero==otraCarta.numero && this.valor==otraCarta.valor) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        Carta otraCarta = (Carta) obj;
        if(this.palo.equals(otraCarta.palo) && this.numero==otraCarta.numero && this.valor==otraCarta.valor) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Una solución muy mejorable, ya que se repite mucho código. Además, si tuviésemos otros **Wrappers** o clases como una instancia de **Double**, intuyo que también no pasaría los Test Junit 5. No lo he hecho sencillamente porque no se me exige. Todavía queda por responder a la pregunta, **¿cómo hacer este código no solo correcto, pasando las pruebas, sino eficiente, con las menores líneas de código posibles?**

La metodología principal a la que he llegado para que pasen las pruebas unitarias, ha sido el siguiente:
Tomando como ejemplo el Integer, primero en el if compruebo si la instancia de Carta y el objeto no tienen la misma clase, y además el objeto es una instancia de Integer, que viene dado por:

```
this.getClass()!=obj.getClass() && obj.getClass().equals(Integer.class)
```

Entonces me dedico a crear una instancia de **Carta** con la que poder comparar rutinariamente mi equals en clase Carta, a partir de uno de mis constructores, específicamente:

```
        Carta otraCarta=new Carta((int) obj);
```

Así que, la solución a tu problema, en base a mi solución aquí descrita, al ser similar al mío (más o menos), debería componerse de modificar tus constructores de **Empleado** para que en cada posición del array se pueda hacer *casting* a String, la estructura posiblemente sea un **if**, pero ya dependerá específicamente de tu clase y sus atributos.

Comment: Buenas! Gracias por responder. Lo solucione de otras maneras pero no de esta. Pues era un trabajo que necesitaba entregarlo un dia concreto y se tenia que hacer. Asi que le di otra vuelta y ya. Revisaré tu respuesta con profundidad y cuando tenga tiempo a ver si lo miro. De nuevo, Gracias, y bienvenido al foro.